# Autofill doesn't work for Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, autocomplete, frontend

I faced with the problem: Autocomplete doesn't work for some form fields in Firefox (v.58.0.1 + Win10). Everything works fine in Chrome, but in FF it works for fields with default basic name attributes only.

For example, here autocomplete **works** fine:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="name">
```

And when I customize name attribute, it **doesn't work**:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="myName">
```

I set appropriate FF setting flags to keep form data. I tried to use so called tokens for autocomplete attribute: autocomplete="home address" and added id attributes to the fields. But I don't have it worked. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on both FF 58.0.1(64 bit) and Chrome 64.0.3282.140(64 bit) and both work fine with code from bellow, are you sure that you have enabled auto complete in FF?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="get">
   <input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="myName">
   <input type="submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Jakub, thank you for answer. Yeah, your code works fine in the both Chrome and FF. And it means my FF settings are ok for autocomplete. What else can it be? Probably because the form is a part of React component.